# is there any force on a tennis ball that is being thrown in the forward direction after it leaves the persons hand?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

is there any force on a tennis ball causing it to go forward after it leaves the person hands.
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Not unless there is wind in that same direction. (or a large source of gravity)

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Could you expand on your question and talk about what you think? As it is currently written, this question seems like you just want the solution to a homework problem, which is considered off topic here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [I]s there any force on a tennis ball **causing it to go forward** after it
>   leaves the person hands[?]

No.

Forces are required to change the speed or the direction of movement of an object. In an idealized world with no friction and no air drag, a ball rolling on a surface would do so forever because there is no (net) force acting on it.

After in a real, air filled world, the ball has left the hand, two things will happen:

1. Its speed towards the ground will steadily increase because of the force of gravity. This force is pointing downwards.
2. The speed in the direction of the throw will steadily decrease because of air drag. This is a force that always points in the opposite direction of the motion.

Answer (score 1):

On Earth only gravity will continue to accelerate the ball in the $y$ direction ($F_y=-mg$) while in the $x$ direction (assuming the throw is parallel to ground) there will be only the acquired speed $v$ so that the poistion in any moment will be $x=vt$ and $y=y_0-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$.

If you can't neglect airdrag you may want to add a term $-\beta v$ in the force equation.

In space... no. Force quit being applied in the exact moment the ball leaves the hand.

Comment: $-\beta v^2$ ? I think

Comment: It depends by the fluid you are moving into and by the regime (stoke's regime or turbolent). It could be both, a term proportional to velocity and one to the square of it.